# Prove that $f(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: connectedness, lipschitz-functions, diffeomorphism

Given that $f$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and that $f^{-1}$ is lipschitz from $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can't we say that as $f^{-1}$ is lipschitz then it is continuous , and as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is clopen then $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is also clopen, and since $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is connected , then $f(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathbb{R}^2$.

($f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ of class $C^1$)

Comment: No. $f(\mathbb R^{2})$ is clopen in itself in the subspace topology (which is vacuous statement). You have not proved that it is clopen in $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Also, continuity is not enough, take $f = \arctan \times \arctan$ (that is, the inverse is not globally Lipschitz, but you are only using continuity in the proof). So, for this to have a hope of being true, the proof must use the boundedness of the derivative of the inverse.

Comment: Okay, but can't we at least be able to prove that $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is open ?

Comment: Open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I mean

Comment: It is open since it is the inverse image of $f^{-1}$ of an open set.

Comment: Hadamard's global inverse function theorem might help if $f$ was $C^2$.

Comment: If we   equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one of the usual norms, would it help ?

Comment: All norms are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so no.

Comment: If we used that $f^{-1}$ is lipschitz and that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete if equiped with a usual norm, can't we prove that $f(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is closed ? (Using sequences )

Comment: It is closed because $f^{-1}$ is continuous. You already established that. You need to show surjectivity.